# How to make this jQuery driven page snappier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have a contact script. It uses jQuery for it's ajax requests and animations.

I also use it with a hashchange plugin to fix the back button. The slow part lies there.

After finishing the animation of the 'flip', the form fades slowly. The browsers seem to block for a sec. I'm trying to make it snappy (no blocking).

Here is the function responsible for handling the hash change event:

```
handleHashChange : function () {

    // Get the name of the object and cache it
    var self = this,

    // Get the current hash
        hash = window.location.hash,

    // Cache the form height var
        formHeight = '';

    // If the hash is #send or #error, don't do anything
    if (hash === "#sent" || hash === "#error") {        
        return; 
    }

    // Change the page title back to the default
    if(self.documentTitle && self.documentTitle != undefined) {
        document.title = self.documentTitle;
    }

    // Reset all inputs in the form
    self.inputs.val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

    // Get the height of the form
    formHeight = self.getHeight(self.form);

    // Show the transition              
    self.showTransition(self.response, formHeight, function() {

        // Show the form
        self.form.fadeIn('fast', function() {

            // Show the button
            self.button[0].style.display = 'block';

            // Focus the first input
            self.inputs[0].focus();

        })

    })
}
```

The whole code can be seen from the link below, it's fully documented:

http://www.coolcontact.co.cc/beta/1.3/js/main.js

You can see I have used a lot of tips I found on the internet to optimize this script, except using javascript's native 'for' in place of '$.each()' , but it's not that big of a deal here.

If anyone wants to see the slowness, try sending an empty message (validation is disabled) from the link below then click the back button in your browser:

(note: it's not in English, but  guess it's pretty self-explanatory ^^)

http://www.coolcontact.co.cc/beta/1.3/

So how can I make it more snappy?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you've put together a nice GUI!

Comment: I think it's pretty darn snappy already!!

Comment: I agree, it looks very good here. What browser are you using?

Comment: Thanks everyone, @cambraca: I tested it with FF, IE, Opera, safari and chrome. FF was the slowest to respond.

Comment: It looks just as good on FF.. on IE9 it runs good, but there's some styling problem, you might want to take a look at that (basically you can't see what you write on all but the first field)

Comment: @cambraca: the IE9 problem happens because it doesn't support Arabic yet. All Arabic websites are broken on IE9. I will try to test it on another machine using FF. Thanks.

Comment: use the Firebug profiler if you want, but I agree with Dutchie432, it's fast already

Comment: Oh that is so bad :S just when I thought IE was finally worthy of my appreciation...

Comment: I'm concerned that you aren't declaring your variables `hash` and `formHeight` with `var`

Comment: @Ravindra Sane: I've used it, and my functions were fast. Thanks. @cambraca: yeah, I know... we all have put our hopes on it ^^. @Peter Bailey: All the variables are declared with `var` and I use a comma to make it validate in jsLint.

Comment: That is a beautiful design. I don't see anything about it I would want to change.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty quick already, but here's something I noticed with your code.

This "if" statement is a bit redundent.

```
if(self.documentTitle && self.documentTitle != undefined) {
    document.title = self.documentTitle;
}
```

The call to "self.documentTitle" will return evaluate to "false" if its value is "undefined", so you don't need the second "self.documentTitle != undefined".

You could just use the follwing instead:

```
if(self.documentTitle){
    document.title = self.documentTitle;
}
```

Remember, the values false, null, undefined, 0 and an empty string all evaluate to a false boolean value.